# Build and run an app on simulator using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I have the following goal to achieve: build and run an `.app` application using `xcodebuild` and `ios-sim`.

I'm using the following script to build the application.

```
xcrun xcodebuild \
  -scheme $XCODE_SCHEME \
  -project $XCODE_PROJECT \
  -configuration Debug \
  -destination generic/platform=iOS \
  -derivedDataPath \
  build
```

Then for running it, I'm using

```
ios-sim launch MyApp.app/ --devicetypeid "iPhone-6-Plus, 9.1"
```

Each time I receive the following message:

> Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested
>   architectures: ?

What is happening, that the app doesn't run?

**Note:** if I run the second command (`ios-sim...`) against the `.app` built from Xcode (the one contained in derived data) the procedure works fine.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why are you doing this instead of just running and building a project in XCode?

Comment: Are you sure you have this simulator installed? from the error it appears that the specific device you're trying to run doesn't exist in your machine

Comment: @HaydenHolligan Needed in order to do test automation.

Comment: @JulianE. Yep. Tried with the app built with Xcode and it does work.

Comment: What is the result of doing `ios-sim showdevicetypes`

Comment: @l'L'l The result is to launch the application for that simulator. It works if I have the .app created through Xcode.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is maybe the simulator build from Xcode is somehow different from the CLI `xcodebuild` one.

Comment: @l'L'l Sounds strange to me. I'm trying different options in order to do it.

Comment: @l'L'l Figured out the solution if you interested in.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok. Figured out the issue.

You need to specify the correct `destination`. For example.

```
xcrun xcodebuild \
  -scheme $XCODE_SCHEME \
  -project $XCODE_PROJECT \
  -configuration Debug \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6 Plus,OS=9.1' \
  -derivedDataPath \
  build
```

In this way Xcode will create the folder (called `build`) containing your products (in particular look at `Debug-iphonesimulator`). The `build` dir is created within the dir you are running the `xcodebuild` command.

Now you can point that folder in order to run the `ios-sim` command (see [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) for more references) or `simctl` (see [iOS 8: Building custom simulators](http://ericasadun.com/2014/06/18/ios-8-building-custom-simulators/) and [Build And Run iOS Apps In Commmand Line](http://dduan.net/post/2015/02/build-and-run-ios-apps-in-commmand-line/) for more info).

Comment: how to pass same simulator with different IDs in the -destination?

Comment: Like I have 2 simulators of iPADs

 i) platform:iOS Simulator, id:0F9084E0-4E0D-43F7-AD3D-AB959744BD09, OS:9.3, name:iPad 2 
ii) platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E05355C-EF57-4771-96D4-0F9FCF24A0D2, OS:9.3, name:iPad 2

Comment: How to run a workspace based project i.e project containing multiple pods projects. Please paste here complete command to run a -workspace

Comment: @QadirHussain I used the method above today to build my workspace project. I just replaced `-project $XCODE_PROJECT` with `-workspace $XCODE_WORKSPACE`

Comment: It build ok but didn't run the simulator

Comment: Seems the second link in "more info" is dead, just FYI: http://dduan.net/post/2015/02/build-and-run-ios-apps-in-commmand-line/ - do you have an updated link for this reference? I'm curious about it's contents if it still is publicly available.

Comment: @BHendricks I cannot find it anymore. So, sorry.